# send two variables by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

hey guys i have a problem when i'm trying to send two variables by ajax 
i did the same code w3schools used in this link 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp…
but it only works when i use one variable only !!
my code :

```
<script>
function showHintname() {
    var ln = document.getElementById("lname").value ;
    var fn= document.getElementById("fname").value ;
    if (fn.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint-name").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }

    else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint-name").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        //xmlhttp.open("GET", "ini/name.php?f=" + fn , true); // working

        // xmlhttp.open("GET", "ini/name.php?f=" + fn &'l=' + ln , true); // not working
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "ini/name.php?f=1&l=1", true); // not working
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this it will work

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "ini/name.php?f=" + fn+ "&l=" + ln , true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  method: ,
  url: ,
  data: { var1: data1, var2: data2 }
}, done(function(data) {
  //Do some actions
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ini/name.php?f=" + fn &'l=' + ln , true);
```

This statement doesn't work because the & symbol is not inside the quotes. You should also as a general practice, try to be consistent with single/double quotes. This should work

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ini/name.php?f=" + fn+ "&l=" + ln , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function showHintname() {
 var ln = document.getElementById("lname").value 
 var fn= document.getElementById("fname").value ;
 if (fn.length == 0) { 
   document.getElementById("txtHint-name").innerHTML = "";
   return;
 }

 else {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("txtHint-name").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
 //the url
 var url = "ini/name.php?f=" + fn + "&l=" + ln;

 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

 xmlhttp.send(null);
}
}
```